# Browser Java Plugin Detection

Tags: java, javascript, browser, plugins, cross-browser

What is the preferred method to determine if the Sun Java Plugin is installed in the browser?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[java deployment toolkit](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html#deplToolkit)

```
script src="http://java.com/js/deployJava.js"

if (deployJava.versionCheck('1.6'))
{ 
alert("1.6 installed")
}
```

Comment: this doesn't works always. (1) If its disabled in firefox it says not installed. (2) on lion os x, even when its disabled in all browsers, it tells installed

Answer (score 2):

You may also consider [PluginDetect](http://www.pinlady.net/PluginDetect/JavaDetect.htm) script.

Comment: unsigned applet

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer for your exact question but is offered as a solution for determining the browser itself. Don't be too harsh, this is really old code that I wrote some time ago.

```
import java.applet.*;

public class BrowserDetector extends Applet {

    public void init() {
        if (isNetscape()) {
            System.out.println("This browser is a Netscape Browser.");
        }
        if (isMicrosoft()) {
            System.out.println("This browser is a Microsoft Browser.");
        }
        System.out.println("VM Type: " + getVMType());
    }

    public static boolean isNetscape() {
        try {
            Class.forName("netscape.applet.MozillaAppletContext");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("This browser is not a Netscape Browser.");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static boolean isMicrosoft() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.ms.applet.GenericAppletContext");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("This browser is not a Microsoft Browser.");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public String getVMType() {
        String theBrowser = "No VM";
        String appletContext = getAppletContext().toString();
        if (appletContext.startsWith("sun.applet.AppletViewer"))
            theBrowser = "APPLETVIEWER";
        else if (appletContext.startsWith("netscape.applet."))
            theBrowser = "NETSCAPE";
        else if (appletContext.startsWith("com.ms.applet."))
            theBrowser = "MICROSOFT";
        else if (appletContext.startsWith("sunw.hotjava.tags.TagAppletPanel"))
            theBrowser = "HOTJAVA";
        else if (appletContext.startsWith( "sun.plugin.navig.win32.AppletPlugin"))
            theBrowser = "NETSCAPEPLUGIN";
        else if (appletContext.startsWith( "sun.plugin.ocx.ActiveXApplet"))
            theBrowser = "MICROSOFTPLUGIN";
        else if (appletContext.startsWith( "sun.plugin.viewer.context.IExplorerAppletContext"))
            theBrowser = "MICROSOFTPLUGINJRE1.4";

        return theBrowser;
    }

}
```